# Convent a text file into an Excel column of cells, each cell with a variable number of text lines?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conversion

I have a text file like in the example. Each field, which consists of a variable number of rows, is separated from the next field by a blank row.

How can I convert this text file in an Excel table (a single column)? Consecutive chunks of text must occupy consecutive Excel cells and be displayed exactly as they are (not as a continuous strings or with other modifications).

Example of text file:

---

Convert a table to text. Select the rows or table you want to convert to text. Under Table Tools, on the Layout tab, click Convert to Text. In the Convert to Text box, under Separate text with, click the separator character you want to use in place of the column boundaries. Click OK.
Video: Convert text to a table - Word - Office Support
https://support.office.com/.../Video-Convert-text-to-a-table-9bc4b562-4f88-4ba0-9a5...

Create the table. Select the text that you want to convert to a table. Select Insert > Table and then select Convert Text to Table. Set the column width: For Separate text at, select the separator character that you used in the text. Select OK.
Convert text to a table or a table to text in Word 2016 for Mac - Word for ...
https://support.office.com/.../Convert-text-to-a-table-or-a-table-to-text-in-Word-2016-...

Insert separator characters—such as commas or tabs—to indicate where you want to divide the textinto table columns. ... In this example, the tabs and paragraph marks will result in a table that has 3 columns and 2 rows: ... On the Insert tab, click Table > Convert Text to Table.
How to Convert Text to a Table in Word - dummies
www.dummies.com/software/microsoft.../how-to-convert-text-to-a-table-in-word/

By Faithe Wempen. Word 2013 allows you to convert text to a table in with a few simple clicks — if you already have some text that's separated into rows and ...
How to Convert Text to Table in Word 2010 - dummies
www.dummies.com/software/microsoft.../how-to-convert-text-to-table-in-word-2010/

By Dan Gookin. If you started working on your Word 2010 document before you discovered the Tablecommand, you probably have lists set up using tabbed text.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the Import... wizard under the File menu, and import the text
   file.  There was no option to use a Return character as the
   delimiter, so I left it blank.  This imported the file above into 5
   rows, each having only a single (very long) line.
2. Select the column, and choose Format > Cells...
3. Under the Alignment tab, check the Wrap text checkbox.
4. Select the column, and change the font and font size to be the same as the original text file.  The sample above was Arial
   11.5 pt.
5. Adjust the width of the column to match the line length or the input file.

These steps gave me this result:

[image]

Note: if the input file is truly plain text, it won't have live hyperlinks.  The first two fields in your example text do have live hyperlinks.

Comment: Unfortunately my Excel 2002 fills each row (cell) with a single line of text. So your method does not work. For the example I have given, I will get 25 cells instead of just 5.

Comment: If you're getting 25 lines, then the Import part isn't working correctly.  It's using something besides a return character as the delimiter.  If you can't get it to use return, I'd suggest editing the text and replacing each return character with a return and an asterisk or pound sign.  Then use the extra character as the delimiter.